# SQL Select Statement in foreach reference returns error. Razor Webpages v3

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, razor

When I want the database to return information for a user that changes for each user, I use this statement:

```
 @foreach (var BoxId in db.Query("SELECT BoxText FROM FourByFourContent WHERE FourByFourId=(@0)", FourByFourId))
    {
        <div class="box">@db.QueryValue("SELECT BoxText FROM FourByFourContent WHERE BoxId=(@0)", BoxId)</div>            
    }
```

However, when executed in the browser I get this error:

> No mapping exists from object type WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to a
>   known managed provider native type

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a type converting issue. You're selecting BoxText in your first SELECT - what type is it?

Comment: It is a text in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//here you are selecting the BoxText to plug into variable BoxID
@foreach (var BoxId in db.Query("SELECT BoxText FROM FourByFourContent WHERE FourByFourId=(@0)", FourByFourId))
//then you are querying for the content where the BoxId is 'BoxText'
<div class="box">@db.QueryValue("SELECT BoxText FROM FourByFourContent WHERE BoxId=(@0)", BoxId)</div>
```

It wouldnt make sense to query with a `BoxId` that is equal to `BoxText`. In addition, you are making several trips to the database for nothing.

```
 @foreach (var boxText in db.Query("SELECT BoxText FROM FourByFourContent WHERE FourByFourId=(@0)", FourByFourId))
    {
        <div class="box">@boxText</div>
    }
```

Comment: Now I get "WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord"